# Build to iOS Device: DTDeviceKit: deviceType from <DEVICEID> was NULL

Tags: appcelerator

New project in Appcelerator Studio builds and compiles to simulator with no problem. Choosing an iOS device to build it do presents an error after invoking xcodebuild.

I've downloaded the Geocoder-Sample project from Appcelerator and it compiles and sends to the same device no problem.

There is no code done. I'm using the stock template from a new project creation and trying to send it to the iPhone.

The error being shown:

[ERROR] :  2019-06-08 09:29:00.360 xcodebuild[5225:52111]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 5bf3c1e2f2cc885d5f3db33825847fab3e4f80b6 was NULL
[ERROR] :  2019-06-08 09:29:00.361 xcodebuild[5225:52111]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 5bf3c1e2f2cc885d5f3db33825847fab3e4f80b6 was NULL

I'm using a correct provisioning profile and developer certificate.

Answer (score 4):

We got this problem in Flutter after updating XCode. We've solved it executing:

```
flutter clean
```

Answer (score 3):

Flutter- In my case, I have deleted the previous build with same bundle Id.

Answer (score 2):

I used `react-native run-ios --device <device name>` from the command line and encountered this error. It turned out that I had no Apple Developer account added in Xcode, and there was no message about it when building from a shell. I went to `Xcode > Preferences... > Accounts` and added one.

Then Xcode suggested adding my phone as a device for development to my Apple Developer account. After doing so, errors disappeared, and an app got installed on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and was able to fix it by running a build in Xcode and then trusting the developer on the device (iOS > Settings > General > Profiles & Device Management).

If not, try to switch to enable the legacy build system in the xcode workspace.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was import GoogleMaps in AppDelegate.swift, after delete plugin I missed to delete import it from AppDelegate.swift file,

After delete imports project work will...

Answer (score 0):

I met this error after update Xcode. I solved it by changing the Build System to `Legacy Build System`.

Answer (score -3):

If you run **ionic cordova run ios --list** and you see undefined then most likely it's iTunes' Sync over Wi-Fi.  Go to iTunes and turn that off then reconnect your device.  You should now only see one device which won't be undefined.